# UIPicker view de array

Tags: ios, swift

Gente boa noite...
Estou com o seguinte problema : Preciso inserir um picker view em minha aplicação , esse picker view recebe os dados de um array, e quando o usuário clicar em um botão dispara uma action que pega o valor do pickView (pode ser até a posição no array) e altera o texto de uma label.
Ja tentei vários tutorias na internet, porem todos ou dão problema de compilação , ou ao testar no iphone da problema ao abrir a view.
Alguém poderia por favor  ou me indicar um bom tutorial bem explicado e que esteja funcionando ou poderia me mostrar como faz ? 
Obrigado

Comment: Sua dúvida está desde a criação deste `UIPickerView` e preenchimento dele, ou somente obter o valor selecionado para preencher o `UILabel`?

Comment: Amigo consegui povoar o picker view... Como faço para saber qual opção o meu user selecionou, ou seja qual função posso executar para saber qualopção esta selecionada ? tipo um .text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sendo que você já tem o `UIPickerView` definido e com os devidos valores, para obter quem está selecionado, caso você só tenha um componente, faça assim:

```
let selecionado: Int = pickerView.selectedRowInComponent(0)
```

E com a variável `selecionado`, você identifica o valor do *array* para preencher o seu `UILabel`.

Comment: Essa função retorna a linha selecionada né ? o que seria este 0 ?

Comment: É porque o seu `UIPickerView` pode conter vários componentes, quando aquela "roda" é dividida em várias, por exemplo, o `UIDatePickerView` é como se fosse um picker view normal, só que com um componente para o dia, outro pra hora e etc. Então se você só tem um componente, o zero quer dizer que estou pegando este primeiro. O número de componentes você define no *delegate* `numberOfComponentsInPickerView`.

Comment: Entendi muito obrigado...